# Create parent Links in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that looks like this

```
project_id user_id
1          1 
1488179    1 
1          2 
100        2 
1488179    2 
260279     2 
1          3 
11578      3 
5          3
```

where a user is following projects. A user can follow multiple projects. I want to link projects when a users is following both of the projects.

What I am aiming for is something like this

```
project_ID project_ID User_id
1          1488179    1
1          100        2
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in mysql?

this is what I tried so far:

```
select distinct a.project_id, b.project_id, a.user_id   
from follow_projects as a  
inner join follow_projects as b  
on a.project_id > b.project_id
and a.user_id = b.user_id
```

Comment: What is the outcome you are getting when you run that query?

Comment: how do your expected results even make sense? if you were to try and link other users by project then you would have a lot of other results

Comment: @JohnRuddell I would like to create a graph of projects by the users that follow them. It is more like a parent to children relationship where all there is a link between children of the same parent

Comment: @user3112486 even after your edit it still doesn't make sense... look at user 3... they have the same 'parent' project_id

Comment: @JohnRuddell the parent in this case will be the user_id with each user_id having multiple children 'project_id'. For example for user 3, there would be a link between projects 1 and 5

Comment: @user3112486 exactly. so why are users 1 and 2 linked together by a project_id of 1 and not user 3 who also has project_id 1? doesn't make sense to me.